# opencv SVM Prediction

Tags: opencv, machine-learning, classification, svm

I am currently working on age estimation and extracting features using Gabor Filters. I have decided to classify ages using a SVM, the training is successful and it does not take a long time since the feature vectors are only about 3000 in dimensions by a 1000 training samples.

The problem is that when I want to predict an image, the result returned is always 18 (I pass the feature vector of the testing image to the predict function of the SVM). But when I predict an age from the training set the result is always correct. I do not know why this is happening. Any help will be appreciated.

Also, an observation is that whether or not I change and/ or include the SVMParams the prediction still outputs the same value.